# Why is the icon for password a lock, should it not be a key?

Tags: icons

When I did a google search for "password icon", there are way more for "lock" than "key". Maybe this is what the masses expect, but should one follow the trend, or start a new trend in the name of progress?

To me a key is the thing that grants you access. If you go to a locked door or a gate with a padlock on it, and in your hand is a lock, you're not doing to get access by inserting a lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re not wrong, a password is more like a key than a lock. But, I can think of three reasons why a lock is shown.

1. In the real world, the lock is the signifier that you need a key. We just viscerally know that when we see a lock, a key is required. The lock icon represents the password *field* that accepts the password, rather than the password itself.
2. Sometimes we need to communicate to the user that an ordinarily locked item has been unlocked. The locked icon / unlocked icon is a nice visual binary. It can reinforce to the user that a password isn’t necessary.
3. In the old days, a key icon was often used in the API world to prompt for a secret key - similar to a password, but also distinct in meaning. Thus it has an existing semiotic meaning, assigned to another function.